# Why is the MySQL for Excel freezing when data append is attempted?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1. where I am trying to use the MySQL for Excel plugin to append data in an Excel spreadsheet to a MySQL database table. Each time I try to do this by clicking the "Append" button, the plugin freezes and nothing gets done. Considering that I only installed the plugin yesterday, I am sure that I am running the latest version, whatever it may be.

The server that the plugin is connecting to is my localhost server, and I have checked to make sure that it is on, so I am sure that it is not the problem.

What can I do about this? Is this a known problem with the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: Which plugin are you using exactly?

Comment: @edvinas.me MySQL for Excel http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the folks at Oracle released MySQL for Excel v1.2.1 with a major bug that causes it to not work. Uninstalling 1.2.1 and downgrading to v1.2.0 seemed to do the trick. I will hold back on an upgrade until 1.2.2 is released. Just as a sidenote for anyone reading this with similar problems, this is an issue in Excel 2013. I cannot say whether other version of Excel have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MySql for Excel 1.1.2. Uninstall current version and than install 1.1.2
Tried and tested in Excel 2013 with Windows 7.

Right now, latest MySql for Excel version is 1.3.2 and it has the same problem.

Comment: 1.3.2 is an experimental release. As I have no faith in the experimental release, I have not tried it. 1.2.1 seems to be working just fine for me though.